# I cannot resolve the error for include

Tags: flex4.5

I'm new to flex.

Whenever I put `<x ml list>` in flex it shows could not resolve to a component implementation:

```
<mx: XML List id="tree Data">
```

I'm having many issues with this. Please give me ideas to resolve the error.

Comment: Probably you should have a look at the tutorials of this product and thus start from the beginning. You cannot ask a good question if you know nothing and don't look a little by yourself.

Comment: hmm sure sir could you please give your mail if i have some doubts means i will contact you

Comment: am a beginer of flex tell me some tutorial for refer flex .. currently we are using flex 4.5

Comment: Hi, I myself know nothing about flex... But I think google is your friend. kindly read [ask] before asking your next question

Comment: Is there any space between "mx: XML List" as you have written ?
it should be like 
`code` <mx:XMLList id="treeData">